# CUDA 5.0 does not see the Tesla C2050

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, cuda

I have upgraded our development machine which is equipped with two Tesla C1060 cards and one Tesla C2050 card to CUDA 5.0.
The machine runs Windows Server 2008R2 (x64). All three cards are visible in the Windows device manager with NVIDIA driver version 9.8.13.694. When running the deviceQuery.exe that ships with the 5.0 SDK only the two C1060 cards are listed. CUDA does not see the Tesla C2050 card.

Has anybody experienced similar problems with CUDA 5.0 and found a fix?

Comment: I use a lot of 2090's but I've never mixed 1xxx and 2xxx in the same box, I don't know the answer for you but I'm interesting in what you discover.